# How can this way exclusion of files be achieved in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a PowerShell script on a production server to show me the list of database backup files that are older than 30 days.

I need to see only the files that have the extension of ".bak". However, in my script there is no matching syntax or [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), so I am also getting to see a list of files which have an extension like "filename.foo.bak". These files may be text files or other configuration files on the server for which backups have been taken automatically by the program that uses these files.

How do I enable a match filter so that I see only "*.bak" and not other files as mentioned above?

As mentioned by mjolinor, I have used this script to do the exclusion.

```
gci $paths -recurse -filter *.bak -exclude *.*.bak | ?{!$_.psiscontainer}
```

However, I have learnt that I need to exclude some system folders such as **C:\Windows**.
How can this be accomplished as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
gci *.bak -exclude *.*.bak
```

I tried to reply to your comment, but the code doesn't show up right.  -exclude takes a string[] argument, so:

```
gci -recurse -filter *.bak -exclude *.*.bak,windows |? {!$_.psiscontainer}
```

Comment: Thanks Mjolinor, this works. I have discovered that some system folders like C:\Windows would have to be excluded as well. I learned that -exclude switch works only for files. It would be great if we can add the folders to the exclusion list.

Comment: Without knowing what's in $paths it's hard to give a definitive answer, but if it's picking up c:\windows, that means you're starting in the root of C:. From there, this should work: gci -recurse -filter *.bak -exclude *.*.bak,windows |? {!$_.psiscontainer}. The -exclude parameter takes a string[] argument, so you can specify multiple exclusions.

Comment: You are correct. **$paths = 'C:\','D:\','E:\'**  
I have tried this, but still I get the .bak files in C:\Windows.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to exclude them from the search, you'll have to remove them afterwards. To exclude all files in C:\Windows (or subdirectories):

`gci $paths -recurse -filter *.bak -exclude *.*.bak | Where-Object {!$_.psiscontainer -and $_.fullname -notlike "C:\Windows\*"}`